# glob.glob giving back unordered files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, glob

I have a directory containing multiple image files all called **f"name{i}" for i in range(64).**
I'm performing actions on each image after reading them. To iterate through all the images in the directory I use:

```
img_list = []
    for img in glob.glob(rf"name_results\*.png"):
        img_list.append(img)
        img_list.sort(reverse=True)
        print(img)
```

I desperately tried to sort through the list but that seems to have no affect whatsoever on the output:

```
name_results\name0.png
name_results\name1.png
name_results\name10.png
name_results\name11.png
name_results\name12.png
name_results\name13.png
name_results\name14.png
name_results\name15.png
name_results\name16.png
name_results\name17.png
name_results\name18.png
name_results\name19.png
name_results\name2.png
name_results\name20.png
name_results\name21.png
name_results\name22.png
name_results\name23.png
name_results\name24.png
name_results\name25.png
name_results\name26.png
name_results\name27.png
name_results\name28.png
name_results\name29.png
name_results\name3.png
name_results\name30.png
name_results\name31.png
name_results\name32.png
name_results\name33.png
name_results\name34.png
name_results\name35.png
name_results\name36.png
name_results\name37.png
name_results\name38.png
name_results\name39.png
name_results\name4.png
name_results\name40.png
name_results\name41.png
name_results\name42.png
name_results\name43.png
name_results\name44.png
name_results\name45.png
name_results\name46.png
name_results\name47.png
name_results\name48.png
name_results\name49.png
name_results\name5.png
name_results\name50.png
name_results\name51.png
name_results\name52.png
name_results\name53.png
name_results\name54.png
name_results\name55.png
name_results\name56.png
name_results\name57.png
name_results\name58.png
name_results\name59.png
name_results\name6.png
name_results\name60.png
name_results\name61.png
name_results\name62.png
name_results\name63.png
name_results\name7.png
name_results\name8.png
name_results\name9.png
```

Not sure what I can do to store them in a list as if it's **f"name{i}" for i in range(64)**; meaning starts from name1.png to name63.png in ascending order.

Comment: String sorting in Python sorts lexicographally; `name2` is greater than (after) `name19`. You’ll have to implement any different sorting algorithm. If you have any control on the file naming then zero-fill e.g. name00, name01, etc.

Comment: @barny I would've accepted your answer if had written it. You mentioning lexicoraphical sorting led me to find natural sorting solutions out there. Thanks pal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a *key* in for sorting:

```
import re
img_list = [f"name_results\name{i}" for i in range(12)]
img_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.findall(r'\d+',x )[0]))
img_list
```

output:

```
['name_results\name0',
 'name_results\name1',
 'name_results\name2',
 'name_results\name3',
 'name_results\name4',
 'name_results\name5',
 'name_results\name6',
 'name_results\name7',
 'name_results\name8',
 'name_results\name9',
 'name_results\name10',
 'name_results\name11']
```